# How to select the last row from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

```
  public function addNewPost(Request $request)/****ADD new POST****/
  {
    $this->validate($request,['post_title'=>'required|min:4|max:100',
                              'post_description'=>'required|min:20|max:500'
                            ]);    

    $user_name = Session::get('name');
    $post_title = $request->input('post_title');
    $post_description = $request->input('post_description');


    $addPost = new AddNewPost(['user_name'=> $user_name, 'post_title'=> $post_title, 'post_description'=> $post_description]);
    $addPost->save();
    $addPost->post_id;
    //$addPost = DB::table('userposts')->where(['user_name'=>$user_name ])->orderBy('post_id', 'desc')->get();

    print_r($addAdmin->post_id); //This is printing nothing, i.e. blank.     
  }
```

**post_id** column in *userposts* table is auto incremented. I am trying to get the last post id of the user by *user_name*. I have seen some tutorials and also checked some questions over internet but unable to do what I am trying to get. Can anybody know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: What is `$addAdmin` at last line of your code? It would be `$addPost ->post_id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try first() instead of get() in a query it might help you

```
 $lastdata = DB::table('userposts')->where(['user_name'=>$user_name ])->orderBy('post_id', 'desc')->first();

print_r($lastdata);
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has the **last()** method that you can use.

This is from the docs:

> **last()**
>
> The last method returns the last element in the collection that passes a given truth test:
>
> collect([1, 2, 3, 4])->last(function ($value, $key) {
>      return $value < 3;
>   });
>   // returns 2
>
> You may also call the last method with no arguments to get the last element in the collection. If the collection is empty, null is returned:
>
> collect([1, 2, 3, 4])->last();
>   //returns 4

Here is the example for getting only the last id:

```
Model::pluck('id')->last();
```

Comment: Worst you can do is to load entire collection (million rows?), then iterate over it just to return single element from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method which will not takes much processing is

```
DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

Hope this helps

You can also try

```
 $addPost = new AddNewPost(['user_name'=> $user_name, 'post_title'=> $post_title, 'post_description'=> $post_description]);
$addPost->save();
$addPost->update();
print_r($addPost->post_id); //It will print id..
```

P.S second method is kind of redundant

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`DB::table('userposts')->last()->pluck('user_name')` Is the fastest way . 
Make sure to apply last() first to avoid unnecessary  workload

Answer (score 0):

Please have a closer look at your print statement:

```
print_r($addAdmin->post_id);
```

The `$addAdmin` is not defined within the scope of your function. The best way to get the **last** row from your **database**:

```
DB::table('name_of_table')->last()->pluck('user_name')
```

Here is the documentation on using DB: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database

Comment: You write a wrong query. It should be `pluck('user_name')->last()`